# Можно ли через REST API / WebDAV Яндекс диска получить доступ к разделу Фото?

Tags: rest, yandex-disk

Речь идет о разделе, где загружаются безлимитные фото с телефона. В документации это не раскрыто, а Swagger яндекса недоступен. Может быть кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: Я когда то спрашивал у поддержки, наверно года 3 назад, и мне ответили что нельзя. Будет интересно узнать, если что то изменится или найдётся способ